# Spring 4: return a list of objects per ResponseEntity or another way?

Tags: java, spring, response, multipartform-data

I need to return per ResponseEntity a list of objects. I know, I get at the moment only last object of the list, but I need a complete list. Ideas?

```
@RequestMapping(path = "findAllPhotosByPhotoAlbumTitle", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> findAllPhotosByPhotoAlbumTitle(@PathVariable(value = "albumTitle") String albumTitle) throws IOException {

final List<Photo> allPhotosByPhotoAlbumTitle = photoService.findAllPhotosByPhotoAlbumTitle(albumTitle);

    ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> body = null;

    for (Photo photo : allPhotosByPhotoAlbumTitle) {
        body = ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentLength(photo.getMultipartFile().getSize())
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(photo.getMultipartFile().getContentType()))
                .body(new InputStreamResource(photo.getMultipartFile().getInputStream()));
    }
    return body;
}
```

Comment: Looking at code I presume that you want multiple file download in single request, correct? I would suggest that you zip all files and download zip as single file.

Comment: thank you for your answer. zip file with all images? and then this zip file can I send to frontend? And then? Have you simpler solution? MultiPartFiles as ByteArrayResource etc.?

Comment: I've a photo class with following attributes: public class Photo {private MultipartFile multipartFile; // Getter & Setter }

Comment: Every MultiPartFile contains fileName, InputStream etc... And I will to return a list with MultiPartFiles to frontend, but I can't: Exception: `No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)`